# How to preserve styles when displaying of a CKeditor edited text

Tags: php, asp.net, ckeditor

here is `Description`, a ckeditor-edited text: When paste from Word, only bold/italic formats are preserved: lists, paragraph are shown in line... am I missing a skin ?

```
    <asp:Literal ID="DescriptionLabel"  
     runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Description") %>'/>
```

and another application

```
    <?php echo($row['Description']);?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You sir, need a plugin to do that

http://ckeditor.com/addon/pastefromword

Comment: I got this plugin @Samuel but dont know, how do I use it? I added this and it doesnt work `CKEDITOR.config.pasteFromWordCleanupFile = '<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/ckeditor/plugins/pastefromword/filter/default.js") %>';`